# Is it possible to use JavaScript element id Name as a variable in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, variables

Any idea to make JavaScript id name as a variable.

var tblFruits2 = document.getElementById("table");

```
    //Reference all the CheckBoxes in Table.
    var chks2 = tblFruits2.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    
   
   for (var i = 1; i < chks2.length+1; i++) {
        var x = document.getElementById("table").rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;

       if (i == 1) { document.getElementById('HiddenField1').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 2) { document.getElementById('HiddenField2').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 3) { document.getElementById('HiddenField3').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 4) { document.getElementById('HiddenField4').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 5) { document.getElementById('HiddenField5').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 6) { document.getElementById('HiddenField6').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 7) { document.getElementById('HiddenField7').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 8) { document.getElementById('HiddenField8').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 9) { document.getElementById('HiddenField9').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 9) { document.getElementById('HiddenField10').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 10) { document.getElementById('HiddenField11').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 11) { document.getElementById('HiddenField11').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 12) { document.getElementById('HiddenField12').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 13) { document.getElementById('HiddenField13').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 14) { document.getElementById('HiddenField14').innerHTML = x; }
       if (i == 15) { document.getElementById('HiddenField15').innerHTML = x; }
    }
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('HiddenField' + i).innerHTML = x;`. Notice, that `rows[i].cells[2]` will throw an error if `i` becomes greater than the last index of `rows`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thankyou very much. I exactly trying to use i variable in element id name field. Thanks to save my lot of code writing.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont't you simply create your HiddenFields on demand like this:

You create a parent div in which you want to add your HiddenField:

```
<div id="collectionView">
   <!-- items will be created here -->
</div>
```

Javscript would look like this:

```
var chks2 = tblFruits2.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    
   
for (var i = 1; i < chks2.length+1; i++) {
   var x = document.getElementById("table").rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;

   var HiddenField = document.createElement("div");
   var HiddenField.innerHTML = '<div id="HiddenField' + 'i' + '"></div>';
   // deleteButton.setAttribute("hidden", "true"); 

   var view = document.getElementById("collectionView");
   view.appendChild(HiddenField);
}
```

If you want to add any other attributes to the div, you can do that with `.setAttribute` as I displayed or use the different pre-defined attributes html  provides. Of course you can also append other divs or elements to your HiddenField using `HiddenField.appendChild(new-div);` underneath `view.appendChild`.

If you need to reverse your array (the HiddenFields are created the wrong way round) you can use `var chks2 = chks2.slice().reverse();`.

Using this method would allow you not to have useless code laying around in your html. I can also see the disadvantages, e. g. if the HiddenFields contain different code/information/attributes and are not similar.

*Note: I used a different, more ugly js-code and have not tried the one in this example. Please let me know if this one does not work!*

Comment: Thankyou very much. I exactly trying to use i variable in element id name field. Just `document.getElementById('HiddenField' + i).innerHTML = x;` simple code solve my problem.